# delete remote file using ssh when ssh not working

Tags: linux, ssh

on a remote server I have created a file in /etc/profile.d/x.sh with content

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 1
```

now I am unable to ssh to the remote server. unfortunately ssh was the only way to connect.

```
ssh root@remoteserver
Password:
Last login: Fri Nov 21 18:32:47 2014 from 10.62.95.12
Connection to remoteserver closed.
```

I have tried

```
ssh root@10.62.95.130 rm -f /etc/profile.d/x.sh
Password:
```

but this did not work. Is there any way to delete the file using ssh. Or instruct ssh to continue on error.

Answer (score 0):

Try — `ssh root@server sh` and then  `rm /etc/profile.d/x.sh`

Though `ssh root@server rm /etc/profile.d/x.sh` works for me too.